# Flask App Not Running in Localhost

Tags: python, flask

I'm working through Miguel Grinberg's Flask Mega-Tutorial, and am unable to run the basic app in Part I. I am using Ubuntu, and getting the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/makisupa43/dev/microblog/app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

I have double checked code and all looks correct. Not sure if I'm getting screwed up with VirtualEnv or if it is a separate issue.

Comment: Have you done `pip install flask` inside of your virtualenv?

Comment: @HuuNguyen yes I am inside my virtualenv and have run `pip install flask`.

Comment: What is the output of `flask/bin/pip freeze` ?

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the tutorial, it looks like Miguel skips the step where you actually activate the virtual environment. Run this command from the directory where you're doing all your `pip` installs:

```
. flask/bin/activate
```

This should put you in the correct virtual environment, which will make everything you've installed with `pip` available to your `run.py` script.